# How to write down the recurrence relation for the coefficients $a_n.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the differential equation
>   $(1 + x)y' = py$
>   where $p$ is a constant. Assume that the equation has a power series solution
>   $y= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_nx^n$
>   . Write down the recurrence relation for the coefficients $a_n.$

My attempt : Given equation $(1 + x)y' = py \tag 1$

Consider
 $$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
Then
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$
Now substitute in $(1)$ we have 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n+ x\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=p\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

After that  im not able to proceed  further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$
observe that
$$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}$$

therefore
$$(1+x)y’=py$$
becomes
$$(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}=p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n}=p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}$$
$$a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[(n+1)a_{n+1}+na_n\Big]x^{n}=p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n}$$
which gives
$$a_1 =pa_0$$
$$(n+1)a_{n+1} + na_n =pa_n$$

Answer (score 1):

It should be $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^n =p\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n $$ so rewriting this yield $$ a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty[  (n+1)a_{n+1} + na_n]x^n =p\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n. $$ 
Pairing up the coefficients on both sides we obtain
\begin{align*} a_1 &=p a_0 \\ (n+1)a_{n+1} + na_n &= pa_n \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the index.

You have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n}=p\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n}$$ So, for degree $m$
$$(m+1)\,a_{m+1}+m\, a_m=p\,a_m$$